# Number of JVM running on server when say 4 applications running on the Server

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

So here's my doub. I would like to know the number of JVM instances running on a server for 4 applications.

And if there are more than 1 JVM, how would these interact with the Operating System(what priority) to handle multiple threads.

Hope I'm not confusing anyone with the question.

Comment: Define "4 applications".

Comment: And define "server".

Comment: As for how more than 1 JVM interact with the Operating System: The same as 1 does. Same priority. Unless you or the application requests something different.

Comment: They would be say 4 Java applications. Ranging from anything between a simple add program to a android game. I mean to say that what the applications are should be of no consequence right? Just that they are Java applications. The server would be Apache Tomcat v8.0.

Comment: There is a big different between a standalone Java application and a web application that needs to run in a container (servlet, JEE, other). 4 standalone applications are by definition 4 JVM's. 4 web applications can be one container running all 4, or 4 (different types of) containers, each running 1, or a mix. Question is too broad as stated.

Comment: So is there anyplace i can read about this stuff? how it works? I have tried searching for it, however i had no luck with it

Comment: You could add more detail about your specific circumstances, and you might get a more specific answer.

Comment: A Java program is no different from any other program: every time you execute `java`, you start a new process (the Java virtual machine), which consumes memory, uses CPUs, and can execute threads as any other process can. All the threads of all the processes need access to the CPUs to execute their instructions, whether they're started by the JVM or not.

Comment: This was an interview question that the interviewer asked me when i started to explain to him about multi threading. so I was pretty confused myself :(

Comment: @adarsh and the first idea then is to ask for additional information that you need to answer the question. Since you didn't we can't answer the question just as much as you.